# AppAuth podspec recursive weak_frameworks is not installed as weak

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks, cocoapods, appauth

I have an app with deployment target iOS 9.3.
I'm using the AppAuth library (appauth.io) and in the podspec it has a reference to Apples AuthenticationServices SDK. This SDK is only available from iOS 12+. Therefore it is linked with a .weak_framework reference.

But when running "pod install", the AuthenticationServices framework is embedded as required just like any other reference - not weak/optional as I expected.
[image]

So when the app runs on devices lower than iOS 12, the app crashes with the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AuthenticationServices.framework/AuthenticationServices
  Referenced from: /Users/dkesbras/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7AF7A0D-79A9-48C2-8619-DEF94BBD2D10/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A2697143-C605-4E69-A1A6-9D28ADE53192/LEGOMovieMaker.app/LEGOMovieMaker
  Reason: image not found
Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
```

As per Apples article about weak linking of frameworks (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-BBCJICEC), this should also be visible in the "Other Linker Flags" with the flag -weak_framework. But here it is confirmed that the framework is not correctly weakly linked.
[image]

Do anyone have success with using AppAuth SDK on devices lower than iOS 12 or other SDKs that are utilizing the .weak_framework in cocoapods?

How do I make .weak_frameworks in a recursive podspec work, so the reference gets installed correctly as weak reference in the cocoapods project?